# Array is duplicated on every refresh using ExpressJS and NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await, es6-promise

I have been trying to send the var logtraceArr = []; value to the browser using Expressjs but one first call empty array is displayed on 2nd call array is filled with first called function and on 3rd call array is appended with the same element.

I want the content to be displayed on the first.

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
const fs = require("fs");
const path = require("path");
const readline = require('readline');
const directoryPath = path.resolve(__dirname,"../logtrace-filestore/edepoze-logs");
var logtraceArr = [];
router.get("/",function(req,res,next){
    const fetchFileContentParsed = async (fileContentObj) => {
     
        var logtraceObj = {
            Direction : '',
            FromServer: '',
            ToServer:''
          };
        var pipearray = fileContentObj.toString().split("|");
                for( i=0;i<pipearray.length;i++){
                    var Direction = new Array();
                    Direction = pipearray[5].split("::");
                    if (Direction.length == 2) {
                        logtraceObj.Direction = Direction[1];
                    } else {
                        logtraceObj.Direction = "";
                    }
      
                }
                logtraceArr.push(logtraceObj);
  
        return {
            logtraceArr
          }
    }
    // Iterates all users and returns their Github info.
    const getfileContent = async (files) => {
            const fileContent = files.map((file) => {
                const filePath = path.join(directoryPath,file);
                //console.log("filePath ----->",filePath);
                const readStream =  fs.createReadStream(filePath);
                const fileContent = readline.createInterface({
                input: readStream
                });
                fileContent.on('line', function(line) {
                    const regExp = /\[Event([^]+\])/g
                    var matchedContent;
                    if ((matchedContent = line.match(regExp)) != null){
                        return fetchFileContentParsed(matchedContent) // Async function that fetches the user info.
                    .then((a) => {return a })
                    }
                })
            })
            return Promise.all(fileContent) // Waiting for all the requests to get resolved.
    }
    function readFiles(dirname) {
        //console.log(dirname);
        fs.readdir(dirname, async function (err,filenames)
            getfileContent(filenames).then((a) => {return a })
        });
    }
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.contentType('application/json');
    //console.log(readFiles(directoryPath))
    readFiles(directoryPath,logtraceArr);
    res.send(logtraceArr);
});
module.exports = router;
```

i want the content to be loaded and print the array only once on refresh of the page

Comment: are you sure `fileContent` is an Array of **Promises** - seems it will be an Array of `undefined` since there's nothing being returned in the `.map` callback - also, since you do `then((a) => {return a })` suggests you don't know how promises actually work

Comment: can you explain briefly or code it

Comment: no, I can't code it, I'm asking **you** if `fileContent` is an Array of `Promise`s or an Array of `undefined` - hint: it will be the latter

Comment: are you expecting `line.match(regExp)` to match exactly once (not 0, not 2 or more, but exactly and always 1) for each `(file)`? and why are you creating `async` functions, when none of them use `await`?

Comment: fileContent reads the every individual line in the file using regexp and stores the output in it ...

Comment: no, it doesn't, it is an array of `undefined` since there is no `return` in the `.map` callback - I was referring to `const fileContent = files.map((file) => {` of course

Comment: are you sure that it is an undefined array ,cause my code is working absolutely fine and i'am getting the expected output despite of the issue that i'am facing

Comment: Your code isn't valid. Please correct it and preferably run it through a formatter like Prettier before [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74766913/edit) to fix it up

Comment: no, your code isn't working absolutely fine - as YOU state: *"first call empty array is displayed"* - that's NOT *fine* and is easily explained by the fact that you don't wait for asynchronous code to complete - perhaps [this code](https://pastebin.com/vSsSRfqj) will work better

Comment: I followed your fix without any modificatios there are some erros...is there any other aternative way to connect with you

Comment: there are errors? not surprising, it was a quick hack of your code, untested. What errors

Comment: Error [ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE]: No such built-in module: node:fs/promise
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:835
      throw new ERR_UNKNOWN_BUILTIN_MODULE(request);

Comment: This code makes no sense: it overwrites `logtraceObj` properties in each iteration. `logtraceArr` shouldn't be global variable if it is managed by the function and returned by it. That's just the tip of the iceberg... Maybe trim down your code to small units, and test those units first.

Comment: Can you code it